# The real part of $e^{e^{i\theta}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that a solution for this question exists on SE, I have seen it, but it doesn’t satisfy my query. I couldn’t understand the solution.

Here is an excerpt from one of the answers

$$z = e^{e^{i \theta} }$$

$$\implies z=e^{\cos \theta +i\sin \theta }$$

$$\implies z=e^{\cos \theta} e^{i\sin \theta }$$

$$\implies z=e^{\cos \theta}(\cos (\sin\theta) +i\sin(\sin \theta))$$

I didn’t understand the last line of the answer. Up to the third line, everything is clear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the real part of $ e^{e^{i \theta}} ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550387/what-is-the-real-part-of-eei-theta) The second answer explicitly mentions Euler's formula

Comment: Are you referring to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2550397/42969)? Did you notice that there are more answers, explaining the connection to Euler's formula?

Comment: @MartinR I read all of them, none of them really explain the last part of the answer

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I understood Euler’s formula, but that still doesn’t explain the very last line. If it does, I am not able to infer, and hence I have reposted it

Comment: Yes, one of the answers explained it below. It may seem as stating the obvious for you, but sometimes people don’t notice what right in the front of them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Aditya I'm glad that everything is clear now but I also still believe that this question is a duplicate

Comment: Yeah it is. I even said it’s a duplicate. But since there was no way to obtain an explanation, I had to ask it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Euler's identity we have

$$ e^{i\sin \theta }=\cos (\sin \theta)+i\sin(\sin\theta)$$

Answer (score 3):

$e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ for any real number $t$. Put $t=\sin \theta$ and you will get the last step.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Euler identity to any function:
$$ e^{if(x)} = \cos(f(x))+i\sin(f(x)) $$
Thus, for $ f(x) = \sin(x) $ you will have the obtained value. 
The real part is then:
$$ \mathrm{Re}\{z\} = \mathrm{Re}\{e^{\cos\theta}(\cos(\sin(\theta))+i\sin(\sin(\theta)))\} = \mathrm{Re}\{e^{\cos\theta}\cos(\sin(\theta))+ie^{\cos\theta}\sin(\sin(\theta))\} = $$ $$ = e^{\cos\theta}\cos(\sin(\theta)) $$
I hope the answer is satisfactory.